# Criar apresentação PowerPoint a partir do Delphi (OleObject)

Tags: delphi, powerpoint

Estou tentando gerar uma apresentação no PowerPoint a partir de um Memo, achei um código na internet que usa OleObject, porém não está funcionando.

O que está incorreto? (Uso o Delphi 10.2 Tokyo)

```
uses
System.Win.ComObj
```

Procedimento:

```
procedure EnviarparaPowerPoint;
var
PowerPointApp: OLEVariant;
begin
try
PowerPointApp := CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application');
PowerPointApp.Visible := True;
PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add;
except
Application.MessageBox('Aconteceu um erro na conversão para o PowerPoint !!!',
'Erro', MB_OK + MB_ICONHAND + MB_DEFBUTTON1 + MB_APPLMODAL);
end;

Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;

begin
//Incluir Slide
PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11); //11 é igual a ppLayoutTitleOnly
    
// Editar o titulo do slide
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes('Rectangle 2').Select;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(
Start := 1, Length := 0).Select;

PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Name := 'Arial';
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Size := 30;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Bold := msoFalse;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Italic := msoFalse;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Underline := msoFalse;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Shadow := msoFalse;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Emboss := msoFalse;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.BaselineOffset := 0;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.AutoRotateNumbers := msoFalse;
PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.SchemeColor := ppTitle;
end;
end;
```

Erros:

> Undeclared identifier: 'ppLayoutTitleOnly'
>
> Undeclared identifier: 'msoFalse'
>
> Undeclared identifier: 'ppTitle'

Comment: Você poderia especificar o que não está funcionando. Código de erro?

Comment: Você tem o PowerPoint instalado em sua máquina?

Comment: @WellingtonTellesCunha Adicionei à pergunta os erros.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura Sim, o PowerPoint está instalado na máquina. Porém como vai ser um software que será distribuído para vários usuários vou ter que verificar se o PowerPoint está instalado na máquina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa170976(v=office.11).aspx

`msoFalse` vale 0.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/ppslidelayout-enumeration-powerpoint

`ppLayoutTitleOnly` vale 11.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/ppcolorschemeindex-enumeration-powerpoint

`ppTitle` vale 4.

Comment: Obrigado. Está quase funcionando.  O meu código compilou, mas tem bastante problemas.